# Solo mining: Stratum from pool 0 detected new block at height

Tags: mining-pools, solo-mining, mining-pool-shares

I'm using ckpool which is a solo Bitcoin "pool". If I see this message

```
"Stratum from pool 0 detected new block at height"
```

what does that mean in the context of a solo pool?

In addition, what is the significance of a "share" in a solo pool?

Answer (score 1):

> "Stratum from pool 0 detected new block at height"

The first stratum server you are connected to updated its work to match the state of the rest of the network. That is, someone else found a block and you switched to mining on top of it.

> In addition, what is the significance of a "share" in a solo pool?

It has no meaning at all.